# iPhone 3G blacks out and displays random static

Tags: iphone

Last night the iPhone 3G (my friend's iPhone, not jail-broken) went black and a white fuzzy line would move around the screen.

Powering off and starting again *seemed* to remove the problem.

We have not been able to reproduce the problem since yesterday. What hardware/software fault could be a likely cause for this?  So it would be possible to tell an Apple Genius next time it happens.

Comment: A number of factors, including age, heat, driver crash. Since you cannot reproduce the problem, it could be random and will never happen again.

Answer (score 1):

It's the display connector cable inside the iPhone which can come a little loose. You can open it up and reseat the cable if it happens again. Ifixit.com have guides.